# Angular re downloading images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[This](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/#/phones) is the official Angular tutorial as you know. 
I'ts good but after finishing it I still didn't get answer to my question why is it re downloading all resources when you move from page to page...

I suppose that it is re rendering and re injecting template every time its being requested but i believe there must be way to cache all that information that you already know is not changing. I want to use downloaded page, so that if its being requested second time no request goes to the server, and view gets updated from the cache.

Do Angular provide features for this or i should implement it myself?

Regards.

Comment: Or here is more interesting question (at least for me). When you go to the next view, does angular remove all the previous DOM part that is in view? Maybe that's why it is re downloading and re rendering every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your questions is if AngularJS routing (and the associated `ngView` directive) is tearing -down DOM corresponding to an old route and replacing it with a new DOM sub-tree. The answer is **yes** - route change will result in DOM part (one managed by `ngView`) to be replaced. This is why you see resources (images) being re-downloaded.

All the partials (HTML templates) that AngularJS is downloading are cached in [$templateCache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache) so no need to do custom caching for those. If you want also cache images you should do it by a configuring a web server.

Comment: Is it possible to override that part of behavior to hide DOM sub-tree instead of removing it? (I had done this with jquery, and it works really fine, but now i want to do the same with angular)

Comment: @Vach not out of the box. You would have to write your own version of the `ngView` directive. It shouldn't be too difficult, this directive is rather small: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js